# Visio to CAD to GIS, How to geo-reference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, coordinate-system, cad, spatial-adjustment

I have CAD file converted from a MS Visio diagram, representing power line cables. Data source has no spatial reference.  I converted into shapefile and now I am trying to georeference the vector layer against an existing streets layer.

Any ideas, other than:

1. Rasterize the shapefile
2. Geo-reference the raster using the Geo-reference plugin
3. Compute the affine transformation
4. RastertoVector

Does the Spatial Adjustment vector method in ArcGIS represents a better option?

Comment: Have you tried Geoeferencing toolbar first and use the scale, rotate,and shift ? Because if you use Spatial Adjustment it is pain and long and time-consuming... Once you are good to go then you can do some spatial adjustment if needed.

Comment: I realized that I have CAD poles with X, Y inside, so I used that as my source coordinates for the spatial adjustments. It worked.